# Test react-native app with 'jest-expo' preset trying to import a file after the Jest environment has been torn down

Tags: react-native, expo, ts-jest

I'm trying to implement test for my react native app using expo.

I would like to test a simple component that import expo library (@expo/vector-icons) :

```
const Icon: FC<IconProps> = (props: IconProps) => {
    const colors = useColors();
    const IconComponent = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
        require("../../../../assets/icons/selection.json"),
        'IcoMoon',
        'icomoon.ttf'
    );

    return (
        <IconComponent name={props.name} size={props.size || 20} color={props.color || colors.label}/>
    );
};
```

Here is my test:

```
const iconProps = {
    name: "alert-circle",
    size: 20
}

describe("<Icon/>", () => {
    describe("Rendering", () => {
        it("render default as expected", () => {
            const icon = create(<Icon {...iconProps}/>)

            expect(icon.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
        })
    })
})
```

But i got an error :

> ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest
> environment has been torn down.
>
> ```
>   at Object.get Text [as Text] (node_modules/react-native/index.js:122:12)
>   at Object.get [as Text] (node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/lib/react-native.js:13:26)
>   at Icon.render (node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/lib/create-icon-set.js:120:58)
> ```

Here is my jest configuration :

```
preset: 'jest-expo',
setupFiles: [
        "<rootDir>/jest/setupJestMock.ts"
    ],
testEnvironment: "node",
transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    },
transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ],
```

I've tryed to add :

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
```

In my setupJestMock.ts file but nothing changed.

What i am doing wrong ?
Note that i'm using typescript.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?